# 404 error At the time of installation

Tags: magento-1.9

I upload my previous magento store on new server.then import database on new server.then delete `local.xml` file, then when I run my url for magento installation ,url gives me 404 error.

Any one help me for that.

```
Magento Version:1.9.3.4
```

Comment: Why did you delete **`local.xml`**?

Comment: for installation process

Comment: and just remove from that directory , I have backup `local.xml` file

Comment: delete `var/cache` folder and try

Comment: I delete var/cache folder then try but same error 404

Comment: can you please help me @ Murtuza Zabuawala

Comment: Hello , I install magento store from one server to another , then when i hit on my admin url for login it gives 404

Comment: can you pls help me out this

Comment: You need  local.xml It's all your installation information. Restore it and change  <username> <password> and <dbname> with your current configuration